# Why after the changes the list is not displayed and the functional that I need does not work? How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object in which the array is located, and using the fetch method I get a data object and then I have a list of factory workers + a filter on the page.
Here is my application code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bas-ej8l5
But I had to add two buttons, when the first button is pressed, the list of employees which go to the first shift is displayed, and when the second button is pressed, the employees which go to the second shift.

What I added to the code:
1) in the file today.json added the object **second** (the list of employees of the second shift)
2) added the SecondToday.js file and created the SecondToday component (to display the second shift list)
3) in App.js in state added the defaultTab property with **true** value and then created two methods that change the state and, depending on this, in the render method, display the FirstToday component (list of first shift workers) or the SecondToday component(list of second shift workers).

But after my changes now the list is not displayed at all ....
Here's a new option:
https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-ellis-wbkyr
How to fix the problem? What have I not done?

Comment: Please don't post links to your code. Post the code right here in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is related to the fact that your .json data file is not correctly formatted as json.

[I replaced your json data file with the working one and it now loads correctly.](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-kepler-xsucz)

The 2nd problem of it still not displaying after that is fixed has to do with your data verification check in `SecondToday.js`. You are checking to see if `props.data.group.second` exists, but it's undefined. If you log your props, it shows that your `second` key exists outside of `group`.

Comment: you have removed what i need in the json file, in addition the buttons do not work and do their function

Comment: I want have different lists depending on which button is pressed

Comment: Fixed. I've corrected your json formatting and added the 2nd shift in to my json file.

Comment: when i pressed button "Second Shift" the second list is not displayed, and the white page. Try try it yourself

Comment: I edited my answer to account for this already. Your check in SecondToday.js is invalid. Your "second" array that you're looking for doesn't exist where you're looking for it.

Comment: and then how to make my second array appear on the page when the button is pressed?

Comment: Edited once again to point the function to the data correctly (removed "group"). If you want the data structure to be the same (which you should), then you need to fix your data structuring function to put the result in group and not just in the state itself.